# Service Fabric pub/sub messaging between stateless services

Tags: rabbitmq, azure-service-fabric, message-bus

Whats the best way to implement loosely coupled micro services in  Service Fabric using asynchronous messaging. I want *service A* to publish a message and *Service B* to receive it. Can I use rabbitmq or azure message bus in such cases. If so how do I enable communication with those endpoints in a scaling architecture?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend having a look at this code and/or library.

- https://github.com/SoCreate/service-fabric-pub-sub
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceFabric.PubSubActors/

It allows pub/sub messaging between services and actors, without the need for external dependencies.